# Solving a 2D recurrence diagonal-by-diagonal

Tags: recursion, difference-equations, boundary-conditions

I have a 3D recurrence relation -- which I know can be hard for Mathematica to work with, so I boiled it down to 2D.

We have two functions, $f_1(i,j)$, $f_2(i,j)$ defined on the state space $\{(i,j) | 1\leq i+j \leq n \} $ where $i,j \in \mathbb{N}$ with parameter $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If one drew that state space in a 2D coordinate system, it would be a right-angled triangle with hypotenuse at the diagonal $i+j=n$.

The base cases are:

- $f_1(i,0)=1$  $\forall i$
- $f_2(0,j)=0$  $\forall j$

The recursive dependencies are:

- $f_1(i,j)$ depends on $f_2(i,j)$, $f_1(i+1,j-1)$, $f_1(i+1,j)$ -- except for the edge case $i+j=n$, where the last dependency is omitted
- $f_2(i,j)$ depends on $f_1(i,j)$, $f_2(i-1,j+1)$, $f_2(i,j+1)$ -- except for the edge case $i+j=n$, where the last dependency is omitted

The particular dependencies are:

- $f_1(i,j)=\frac{(i+j-n) f_1(i+1,j)-j f_1(i+1,j-1)-j n r f_2(i,j)}{i-n (j r+1)}$
- $f_2(i,j)=\frac{i n f_1(i,j)-r (i+j-n) f_2(i,j+1)+i r f_2(i-1,j+1)}{n (i+r)-j r}$

Pictorially, we could sketch the recurrence like this:
[image]
Where I did not sketch the dependence between $f_1$ and $f_2$ itself: $f_1(i,j)$ depends on $f2(i,j)$ and vice versa, as described above.

If one tried to solve this recurrence by hand, one would proceed "diagonal-by-diagonal": First, solve for $\{(i,j) | i+j = n \}$, then for $\{(i,j) | i+j = n-1 \}$, ... and lastly get the solutions for (1,0) and (0,1).

I tried to solve this using `RSolve`, but it just outputs its input (i.e. can't solve it). Here is my attempt:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqs = {f1[i, j] == (n*r*j)/(n*r*j + j + n - i - j) f2[i, j] + 
     j/(n*r*j + j + n - i - j) f1[i + 1, j - 1] + (n - i - j)/(
      n*r*j + j + n - i - j) f1[i + 1, j],
    f2[i, 
     j] == (n*i)/(n*i + r*i + r*(n - i - j)) f1[i, j] + (r*i)/(
      n*i + r*i + r*(n - i - j)) f2[i - 1, j + 1] + (r*(n - i - j))/(
      n*i + r*i + r*(n - i - j)) f2[i, j + 1],
   f1[i, 0] == 1, f2[0, j] == 0} // FullSimplify

RSolve[eqs, {f1[i, j], f2[i, j]}, {i, j}] // Flatten // FullSimplify
```

I was able to solve the system for the $i+j=n$ case using Mathematica, but I would be interested in the general solution. Is there a way to somehow "iterate" over `RSolve`, by first solving it for $i+j=n$, then for $i+j=n-1,... , i+j=1$? My problem is that the number of iterations itself is a parameter, namely $n-1$.

If anyone is interested, the solution for $i+j=n$ is:

$f_1(i,n-i) = \frac{r (n+r) \left(\frac{r (n r+1)}{n+r}\right)^i-n r-1}{r (n+r)
   \left(\frac{r (n r+1)}{n+r}\right)^n-n r-1}$

$f_2(i,n-i) = \frac{(n r+1) \left(\left(\frac{r (n r+1)}{n+r}\right)^i-1\right)}{r (n+r)
   \left(\frac{r (n r+1)}{n+r}\right)^n-n r-1}$

*Edit*: How to get the 3D recurrence back from the 2D recurrences, as asked by a comment: If we add a third argument, we can merge the two functions $f_1$, $f_2$ to one function: $h(i,j,k)$ where $k \in \{1,2\}$ with $h(i,j,1):= f_1(i,j)$, $h(i,j,2):= f_2(i,j)$. Then, we would have only one function at the cost of having a third dimension.

Comment: If possible, I think it would be good to include the original 3D problem, since that can give clues that are not obvious from the 2D problem. The reduction to 2D problem may also contain certain prejudices. And what kind of answer are you looking for? Are you looking for a closed form symbolic solution depending on $i$, $j$, $n$, $r$ similar to the formula that you include for $i+j=n$ (that seems optimistic but I do not know) or are you ultimately interested in getting explicit numbers?

Comment: Thanks; yes, I am indeed looking for a symbolic solution depending on $i,j,n,r$. I added information on how to convert between the (initial) 3D recurrence  and the 2D recurrence, for which I also added the explicit expression now. The conversion is pretty straight forward, I did nothing magic there. I exploited mainly that the index for the third dimension ($k$ above) had only values in $\{0,1\}$.

Comment: As you indicate, one must solve a succession of linear problems, one for each diagonal $i+j=k$. The matrix for this linear problem is a $2k\times 2k$ matrix $A_k$ (that depends on $r$, $n$). As a simpler problem, I tried to get Mathematica to symbolically solve something like $A_k^{-1}(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$ which can be written as a nonconstant-coefficient linear recursion in one independent variable, but `RSolve` did not solve it (except if $k=n$ which is constant-coeff). So, your problem seems more difficult than a nonconstant-coeff recursion in one independent var that `RSolve` does not solve.